# Points and lines covering them

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. A subset $S$ of points in plane satisfies the following conditions:

**a)** We can't find $n$ lines in plane, such that every element of $S$ belongs to at least one of these lines.

**b)** For every $X\in S$, we can find $n$ lines in plane, such that every element of $S-\{X\}$ belongs to at least one of these lines.

Find the maximum number of elements of $S$.

As you can see [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2667984&sid=061fdfdfb282d06498dc47a81d0618e0#p2667984), The problem can be solved using linear algebra. But is there a pure combinatorics way to prove it?