# Maximal set of points covered by lines

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

> Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. Let $S$ be a subset of points in the plane satisfying these conditions:
>
> - There does not exist $n$ lines in the plane such that every element of $S$ lies on at least one of them.
> - For all $x\in S$, there exist $n$ lines in the plane such that every element of $S-x$ lies on at least one of these lines.
>
> What is the maximum value of $|S|$?

I believe that the maximum is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$, achieved when $S$ is a triangular array with $n+1$ vertices on each side. However, I'm not sure how to prove this.

**EDIT:** the same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142131/points-and-lines-covering-them?rq=1), but no solution has been given.